# How to fix phpMyadmin login?

Tags: 11.04, apache2, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I've isnstalled phpMyAdmin with `apt-get install phpmyadmin`. When I open "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/", enter "root" as the user name and my MySQL root password and press go, then if I use Firefox, I get offered to download index.php file (and if I agree to download, the file is empty), if I use Opera 11, it says " Connection closed by remote server". What may the reason be and how to fix it?

I use up-to-date Xubuntu 11.04. Reinstalling phpmyadmin did not help, neither did removing AppArmor.

I've tried to use SQLBuddy instead, but there's exactly the same problem. So, I think, the problem is not in phpMyAdmin but in Apache or something.

Comment: open localhost  to see if your apache works or not, similarly run a php script from command line to check you php, and run mysql from terminal to check if it works, if every components, run then you had some problem with phpmyadmin installation. i had similar problem but i checked all components and completely uninstalled and reinstalled from synaptic package manager and everything works fine

Comment: @explorex Apache, PHP and MySQL seem to work.

Comment: Going to reinstall, I've run sudo taskserl removelamp-server and it began uninstalling ALL the packages one by one!

Comment: i think you better install one by one package from synaptic package manager(first mysql, then apache, and mysql) and install phpmyadmin. i tried to install phpmyadmin before anything else and had a great crisis ..lol. and also had problem with lampp package ... apache and mysql crashed .. don't know why but with individual i had no problem and i don't know my phpmyadmin also worked somehow..

Comment: Because I read you tried a different solution, I'd like to offer another suggestion, maybe after you get your phpMyAdmin working: MySQL Administrator (mysql-admin) and MySQL Query Browser (mysql-query-browser).

Comment: @explorex Yes, I've initially installed phpMyAdmin first, supposing it to to install correct LAMP stack as a dependency (and it seemed it did). Now, following your advice, I've "completely removed" every package related to PHP, Apache and MySQL, rebooted, and installed them back step-by-step with Synaptic. And it did not help. The only thing changed - Firefox now doesn't give index.php to download, now just nothing happens when I enter root MySQL root password and press Ok. I am going desperate and considering to reinstall the System back to Ubuntu 10.10 instead of Xubuntu 11.04 I use now.

Comment: do you get php myadmin page?

Comment: also dont forget to check phpmyadmin database in your mysql database and user 'phpmyadmin' or 'pma' user in your mysql(database).user(table)

Answer (score 2):

From the README.Debian file:

> USAGE
>
> The application will be available at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
>    after install if you use one of supported web servers (Apache and Lighttpd
>    at time of writing this). Please note that you need to have enabled PHP
>    support in your webserver (for Apache you can do this by a2enmod php5, for
>    Lighttpd by lighty-enable-mod fastcgi).

You can access this file if you install the phpmyadmin package here: `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/README.Debian.gz`

Answer (score 0):

If you download instead of anything else, it is possible with php configuration.

1. `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf`
2. look for `php_admin_value engine off`, between `<Directory /home/*/public_html>` and `<Diretory>`
3. Add `#` in front of `php_admin_value engine off` to disable it.
4. **REMEMBER! Don't change the value `php_admin_value engine` from `off` to `on`!**
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Wish it helps!